# Pizza Stacking System

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a pizza ordering system. It works up until I tried to make it let you order more than one pizza. How would I use tuples to correctly print off the pizza Size and pizza Topppings without weird list syntax?
I do not know how to use it as namedtuples is new to me. I am putting the pizza details into another tuple. 
The pizza details are: size, topping and cost. The toppings are in a tuple of their own and I do not know how to call the details within calling the topping in another tuple.

This is complicated to explain but any help is appreciated! If you don't understand any bit of it then reply and tell me what, I will try my best to explain it.

Thanks

```
import pygame, collections

pizzaList = []

def order():
    pizzaCost = 0.00
    pizzaSize = None
    small = ["small","£3.00"]
    medium = ["medium","£4.50"]
    large = ["large","£5.00"]
    pizzaToppings = []
    pizzaToppingsList = ["Pepperoni","Chicken","Cajun Chicken","Mushrooms","Red Onions","Sweetcorn","Ham"]
    pizzaToppingsMax = 0


    #pizza size
    print("How big would you like your pizza? ")
    pizzaSizeInput = input("Small (max 2 toppings), Medium (max 4 toppings) or Large? (max 6 toppings) ")

    if pizzaSizeInput == "Small":
        pizzaSize=small
        pizzaCost+=3.00
        pizzaToppingsMax=2

    if pizzaSizeInput == "Medium":
        pizzaSize=medium
        pizzaCost+=4.50
        pizzaToppingsMax=4

    if pizzaSizeInput == "Large":
        pizzaSize=large
        pizzaCost+=5.00
        pizzaToppingsMax=6

    pizzaToppingss(pizzaCost,pizzaSize,pizzaToppings,pizzaToppingsMax,0,1,pizzaToppingsList)

def pizzaToppingss(pizzaCost,pizzaSize,pizzaToppings,pizzaToppingsMax,pizzaToppingCount,y,pizzaToppingsList):
    Toppings = collections.namedtuple('Toppings', ['index','description','price'])

    #pizza toppings
    print("What toppings would you like? ")
    toppingsInput = input(str(pizzaToppingsList) + " ")
    pizzaToppingCount+=1
    print(str(pizzaToppingsMax - pizzaToppingCount) + " Toppings Left")

    if toppingsInput in pizzaToppingsList:
        y+=1
        pizzaToppings.append(Toppings(y, str(toppingsInput), '£0.50'))
        pizzaToppingsList.remove(toppingsInput)
        pizzaCost+=0.50

        if pizzaToppingsMax==2:
            if pizzaToppingCount==2:
                print("Here is your current pizza: ")
                pIndex = "1".ljust(5)
                pDesc = str(pizzaSize[0]).ljust(25)
                pPrice = str(pizzaSize[1]).ljust(7)
                print('{0}{1}{2}'.format(pIndex,pDesc,pPrice))

                for x in pizzaToppings:
                    index = str(getattr(x,'index')).ljust(5)
                    descr = getattr(x,'description').ljust(25)
                    price = getattr(x,'price').ljust(7)
                    print('{0}{1}{2}'.format(index,descr,price))
                finishTopping(pizzaToppings,pizzaCost,pizzaSize)

        if pizzaToppingsMax==4:
            if pizzaToppingCount==4:
                print("Here is your current pizza: ")
                pIndex = "1".ljust(5)
                pDesc = str(pizzaSize[0]).ljust(25)
                pPrice = str(pizzaSize[1]).ljust(7)
                print('{0}{1}{2}'.format(pIndex,pDesc,pPrice))

                for x in pizzaToppings:
                    index = str(getattr(x,'index')).ljust(5)
                    descr = getattr(x,'description').ljust(25)
                    price = getattr(x,'price').ljust(7)
                    print('{0}{1}{2}'.format(index,descr,price))
                finishTopping(pizzaToppings,pizzaCost,pizzaSize)

        if pizzaToppingsMax==6:
            if pizzaToppingCount==6:
                print("Here is your current pizza: ")
                pIndex = "1".ljust(5)
                pDesc = str(pizzaSize[0]).ljust(25)
                pPrice = str(pizzaSize[1]).ljust(7)
                print('{0}{1}{2}'.format(pIndex,pDesc,pPrice))

                for x in pizzaToppings:
                    index = str(getattr(x,'index')).ljust(5)
                    descr = getattr(x,'description').ljust(25)
                    price = getattr(x,'price').ljust(7)
                    print('{0}{1}{2}'.format(index,descr,price))
                finishTopping(pizzaToppings,pizzaCost,pizzaSize)

        anotherT = input("Would you like another topping? ")
        if anotherT == "yes":
            pizzaToppingss(pizzaCost,pizzaSize,pizzaToppings,pizzaToppingsMax,pizzaToppingCount,y,pizzaToppingsList)
        else:
            print("Here is your current pizza: ")
            pIndex = "1".ljust(5)
            pDesc = str(pizzaSize[0]).ljust(25)
            pPrice = str(pizzaSize[1]).ljust(7)
            print('{0}{1}{2}'.format(pIndex,pDesc,pPrice))

            for x in pizzaToppings:
                index = str(getattr(x,'index')).ljust(5)
                descr = getattr(x,'description').ljust(25)
                price = getattr(x,'price').ljust(7)
                print('{0}{1}{2}'.format(index,descr,price))
            finishTopping(pizzaToppings,pizzaCost,pizzaSize)
    else:
        print("That ingredient doesn't exist or you cannot have it.")
        pizzaToppingss(pizzaCost,pizzaToppings,pizzaToppingsMax,y)

def finishTopping(pizzaToppings,pizzaCost,pizzaSize):
    global pizzaList
    pizzaSSSList = collections.namedtuple('pizzas', ['size','toppings','cost'])
    pizzaList.append(pizzaSSSList(pizzaSize, pizzaToppings, pizzaCost))
    inp = input("Would you like another pizza?")
    if inp == "yes":
        print("yes")
        order()
    else:
        print("     ")
        print("Here is your final order: ")
        pIndex = "1".ljust(5)
        pDesc = str(pizzaSize[0]).ljust(25)
        pPrice = str(pizzaSize[1]).ljust(7)
        print('{0}{1}{2}'.format(pIndex,pDesc,pPrice))
        for x in pizzaList:
            topp = str(getattr(x,'toppings')).ljust(5)
            cost = str(getattr(x,'cost')).ljust(25)
            size = str(getattr(x,'size')).ljust(7)
            print('{0}{1}{2}'.format(size,topp,cost))

        print("The grand total is: £" + str(pizzaCost) + "0")
        exit()
def ask():
    inp = input("Hello! Would you like to order a pizza? ")
    if inp == "Yes":
        order()
    if inp == "yes":
        order()
    else:
        ask()

ask()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in python3, you can use the unpacking operator and the print method  to print your list with space separator by default.

```
>>> print(*[0, 1, 2])
0 1 2
```

you can also specify the separator

```
>>> print(*[1, 'pizza', 'peperoni'], sep=' ==> ')
1 ==> pizza ==> peperoni
```

Comment: The star `*` does not belong to the `print()`-function. It is the unpacking operator for iterables. A better wording could be *you can use the unpacking operator for iterables to print a list with ...*

Comment: When I print it currently, it gives [small, someothervalue]. How would I get the small part of this? I already tried size[0]

Comment: So I do not know what the topping will be for the topping one. Same kind of problem. Have you run the code to see it?